# Visual Studio ошибка: "Нет шабонов по указаному пути"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Всем привет, имеется веб приложение, которое использует DLL библиотеки и вот мне понадобилось в них (в DLL ках) кое-что дописать, значит, открыл я библиотеку через dotpeek, экспортировал ее  в исходники.
Открыл, кое-что дописал, хочу скомпилировать.

Открываю:
Файл-Создать-Проект из существующего кода.

Параметры выставляю и при создании проекта, ошибка: "Нет шабонов по указаному пути"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы конкретно дописали(т.к. кода нет(sic!)), из-за чего у вас "фсё сломалас", но я таки спрошу: возможно вы некорректно  использовали`string.Format()`?

Comment: Оригинальное нелокализованное сообщение: "**There is no template at the expected path: {0}**" (продукт: **Visual Studio**). Возможно, поможет с поиском.

Comment: А если создавать проект с нуля, стандартные шаблоны отображаются?